# VIM: Search in multiple split-windows

Tags: vim

I want to  search in VIM in multiple split-windows

Steps:

1. Highlight word under the cursor with '*' in a split-window
2. Press 'n' to jump to the next occurrence in all split-windows without changing
   windows via Ctrl-w-w

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

```
nnoremap <silent> n :exe (search(@/, 'nW') == 0 ? "normal \<lt>c-w>\<lt>c-w>ggn" : "normal! n")<cr>
nnoremap <silent> N :exe (search(@/, 'bnW') == 0 ? "normal \<lt>c-w>\<lt>c-w>G$N" : "normal! N")<cr>
```

This answers the question, but I do not feel like it is in the spirit of vim. I prefer the feel of using the quickfix window.

After using `*` execute the following:

```
:cexpr []|exe "windo vimgrepadd//j %"|copen
```

Now you can use `:cn` and `:cp` to move through the searches. I personally use Tim Pope's [unimpaired.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1590), which provides nice mappings in the form of `[q` and `]q`.

See

```
:h search(
:h quickfix
:h cexpr
:h windo
:h vimgrepadd
:h copen
:h cn
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a macro for it, like: <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>.

Now you can hit <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> to do the search. And you can set up a `map` for it:

```
:nmap YOUR_FAVOURITE_KEY @q
```

Comment: That macro fails if the search is not found and stop its execution